# use array in reading rss feed

Tags: php, xml, rss-reader

I'm Reading many rss feed and store these data in database in my site. for this I'm using

```
 <?php
      include_once 'db.php';
     $url=array(
     'http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition_us.rss','http://feeds.cbsnews.com/CBSNewsWorld'
      ...and many other);

       foreach($url as $key => $value){

       $homepage = file_get_contents('$key[$value]');

         $movies = new SimpleXMLElement($homepage);
         echo '<pre>';
          foreach($movies->channel->item as $opt){
     $title= $opt->title;
          $tittle=mysql_real_escape_string($title);
            $link=$opt->link;
            $links=mysql_real_escape_string($link);
          $des=$opt->description;

        $dess=mysql_real_escape_string($des);

        $sql="INSERT INTO store_feed (title, link, description)
        VALUES ('$tittle','$links','$dess')";

         $result=mysql_query($sql) or die('Error, insert query failed');

        }
          }
        if(isset($result)){
echo "submt successful";
         }

         ?>
```

but it stored only a single URL value..please give me a solution.

Comment: `$homepage = file_get_contents('$key[$value]');` - `$key[$value]` is not the right way to get url from the array. just use `$value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My edited code, which works as I mentioned in the comment.

```
<?php

$url=array('http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition_us.rss', 'http://feeds.cbsnews.com/CBSNewsWorld');

foreach($url as $value){
    $homepage = file_get_contents($value);
    $movies = new SimpleXMLElement($homepage);

    foreach($movies->channel->item as $opt){
        # print_r($opt); // for debugging

        $title = $opt->title;
        $link = $opt->link;
        $description = $opt->description;

        echo 'title: ' .$title. ' - description: ' .$description. ' - link: ' .$link.'<br/><br/><br/>';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Edited my Answer, which works perfectly and shows every movie the rss provides. You have to add the db stuff again, which shouldn't be a big problem, I think.